Is it proper grammar to start a sentence with the word "reference"?
The sentence "Reference these materials" sounds wrong to me, but I cannot figure out why, assuming I'm correct.
The intended meaning is "use these materials to further your understanding".
According to Merriam-Webster, it is defined as an intransitive verb:

1 a: to supply with references
b: to cite in or as a reference


2: to put in a form (such as a table) adapted to easy reference

examples that sound fine to me demonstrate its verb form, and there is nothing wrong with starting a sentence with a verb.
I was going to tell someone using the phrase "Reference [these materials]" to replace it with "Refer to [these materials]", but I can't find any solid documentation on why.

"Reference" has become a jargony synonym for "refer to". The replacement you suggest is valid.

What is the sentence supposed to mean?  Cite the materials? Use them as a resource?

The latter: use them as a resource. I've updated the question.

Well, thanks for explaining the downvotes. Super helpful.

Please add the relevant definitions of the verb, and explain why an imperative sentence can't begin with the base form.


explain why an imperative sentence can't begin with the base form.
This is what I'm trying to get an answer for - whether it's correct or not. Or neither, or both. It sounds wrong to me.


I don't see a big problem with "reference these materials", although I agree "refer to" sounds a little more natural in most contexts.
I think some of it has to do with subtle differences in meaning - "refer to" simply means to look at the source material, while "reference" can suggest a more formal citation process. If you are asked to reference a source, you might need to supply quotes or citations,  but perhaps not if you only need to refer to the source.
I'd say that "reference these materials" can carry a connotation of formality that may not be shared by "refer to these materials", so it may not be the preferred choice in most everyday scenarios.

Sorry, I added more context. The usage is not asking the reader to use the materials in a citation, but rather to further one's understanding.
